# How to remove old imported Views from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I recently downloaded Eclipse Mars, previously I was using Eclipse Kepler. After I imported the old workspace I see some views (`Window > Show view > Other...`) with odd red icons.

[image: Old stale views]

I think those views are no longer valid needs to be removed. How do I remove them?

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the '-clean' option.

Comment: @greg-449 That did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove old plugin packages from your workspace .metadata directory. 
Or just create a new workspace by removing the .metadata folder (carefull old settings will be lost)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the obsolete views by running Eclipse once with a:

```
eclipse.exe  -clean -refresh -clearPersistedState
```

After startup the problem is gone.

But keep in mind that the above command will do some cleanup (e.g. close all open files, reset perspective). Not a big deal, but now you're informed.